# Add Table Extension for Markdown in Laravel 7 and graham-campbell/markdown

Tags: laravel, markdown

My App is based on Laravel 7 and uses `graham-campbell/markdown v13.1` as well as `webuni/commonmark-table-extension v2.1` .

I would like to extend the markdown environment with a class that adds the Bootstrap css classes `table table-striped table-bordered` to the rendered html output in case there is a table defined in the html.

I took a look at a lot of examples and came up with the following solution that does not work, unfortunately.

I define the extension in a file `App\Classes\Markdown\AddTableClassesExtension.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes\Markdown;

use League\CommonMark\ConfigurableEnvironmentInterface;
use League\CommonMark\Extension\ExtensionInterface;
use League\CommonMark\Extension\Table\Table;

class AddTableClassesExtension implements ExtensionInterface
{
    public function register(ConfigurableEnvironmentInterface $environment): void
    {
        $environment
            ->addBlockRenderer(Table::class, new \App\Classes\Markdown\AddTableClassesRenderer())
        ;
    }
}
```

The actual renderer I define in a file `App\Classes\Markdown\AddTableClassesRenderer`

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes\Markdown;

use League\CommonMark\Block\Element\AbstractBlock;
use League\CommonMark\Block\Renderer\BlockRendererInterface;
use League\CommonMark\ElementRendererInterface;
use League\CommonMark\Extension\Table\Table;
use League\CommonMark\HtmlElement;

class AddTableClassesRenderer implements BlockRendererInterface {

public function render(AbstractBlock $block, ElementRendererInterface $htmlRenderer, bool $inTightList     = false)
    {
        if (!$block instanceof Table) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Incompatible block type: ' . get_class($block));
        }

        $attrs = [];

        // Add on the class we need:
        $attrs['class'] = $htmlRenderer->escape('table table-striped table-bordered', true);

        return new HtmlElement('table', $attrs, '', true);
    }

}
```

And finally I add my extension to the config file `config\markdown.php`

```
'extensions' => [
        App\Classes\Markdown\AddTableClassesExtension::class,
        League\CommonMark\Ext\Table\TableExtension::class,
    ],
```

This setup creates html tables, but it does not add the css classes to the table attribute.

When I debug it, I do not even reach my code in the renderer class. For testing I use the following method with a table from the documentation of `League\CommonMark` (https://commonmark.thephpleague.com/1.5/extensions/tables/):

```
public function testMarkdownExtension()
{

    $string = "th | th(center) | th(right)
               ---|:----------:|----------:
               td | td         | td";

    echo Markdown::convertToHtml($string);
}
```

What do I need to do to get this simple extension working?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the issue [Request: Ability to add classes to images.](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown/issues/58) on GitHub I figured it out myself.

I redefined the renderer class

```
namespace App\Classes\Markdown;

use League\CommonMark\Event\DocumentParsedEvent;
use League\CommonMark\Ext\Table\Table;

class AddTableClassesRenderer {

    /**
     * @param DocumentParsedEvent $e
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke(DocumentParsedEvent $e)
    {
        $walker = $e->getDocument()->walker();

        while ($event = $walker->next()) {
            $node = $event->getNode();
            if ($node instanceof Table) {
                $node->data['attributes'] = array('class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and I changed the extension class

```
namespace App\Classes\Markdown;

use League\CommonMark\ConfigurableEnvironmentInterface;
use League\CommonMark\Event\DocumentParsedEvent;
use League\CommonMark\Extension\ExtensionInterface;

class AddTableClassesExtension implements ExtensionInterface
{
    public function register(ConfigurableEnvironmentInterface $environment): void
    {
            $environment
                ->addEventListener(DocumentParsedEvent::class, new AddTableClassesRenderer());
        ;
    }
}
```

Now, the table contains the appropriate classes.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   ...
```